# javascript - filling 2 text boxes with dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a drop down list that will automatically enter dates into text fields.

Filling the text fields is easy, but I don't know where to start when trying to figure out how to dynamically filling those text fields with dates such as "first day of the month through today" or "from the first of the year through today".

This is what I've got so far:

javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datetype option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == $("#datepickstart").val();
    return $(this).val() == $("#datepickend").val();
}).attr('selected', true);
$("#datetype").live("change", function() {
    $("#datepickstart").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    $("#datepickend").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
    });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<select id="datetype" name="datetype"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="LBD">LBD</option> 
<option value="MtD">MtD</option> 
<option value="YtD">YtD</option> 
</select>

<input type="text" id="datepickstart" name="datepickstart" value="">
<input type="text" id="datepickend" name="datepickend" value="">
```

Comment: Second `return` in filter function is unreachable.

Comment: can you give example of  selection of LBD, then what should be datepickstart and datepickend??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result use below option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datetype option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == $("#datepickstart").val();
        return $(this).val() == $("#datepickend").val();
    }).attr('selected', true);

    var d = new Date();
    var today = (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    var fdm = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/01/' + d.getFullYear();

    var fdy = '01/01/' + new Date().getFullYear();

    $("#datetype").on("change", function() {
        var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("value");
        if (selectedVal == 'LBD') {
            $("#datepickstart").val(today);
            $("#datepickend").val(today);
        }
        if (selectedVal == 'MtD') {
            $("#datepickstart").val(fdm);
            $("#datepickend").val(today);
        }
        if (selectedVal == 'YtD') {
            $("#datepickstart").val(fdy);
            $("#datepickend").val(today);
        }

    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/begRax

LBD will fill today's date in both fields
MtD will fill Month's first date and second field will have today's date
YtD will fill Year's first date and second field will have today's date

Comment: You are a wizard. This is nearly everything I needed. However, for "LBD" I was hoping that I could find the correct javascript to define "the last business day". So that when "LBD" is selected on a Friday, Monday's date is returned in both text fields.

Comment: If I am not wrong, are you trying to display last business of that week  i.e Friday's date on both fields are on the second field ??

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish with "LBD" is the previous business day. So if today is Monday the date that will get entered is the previous Friday. If today is Tuesday, the date that would be entered is the previous Monday. So on and so forth.

Comment: @jwabsolution, then this should be another question :)

Comment: Thanks @jwabsolution :)